# A question about commutative algebra II - Huneke notes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, homological-algebra

I am studying [these notes](https://home.adelphi.edu/%7Ebstone/commalg-notes/commalg-2/algebra-notes-II.pdf) by Huneke. I am trying to understand the following result: [image]

I have some questions:

He applies Auslander-Buchsbaum formula. Is the projective dimension of $R/I$ finite?

Why $\operatorname{dim}(R/I)=0$? Is it because $\sqrt{I}=\mathfrak{m}$ ?

Comment: Over a regular local ring all finitely generated modules have finite protective dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is pointed out by Mohan in a comment, a commutative noetherian local ring is regular if and only if all modules have finite projective dimension.

As for the second question, you are right. Since $\sqrt{I}$ is the intersection of all the prime ideals containing $I$, if $\sqrt{I}=\mathfrak m$, then $\mathfrak m$ is the only prime ideal containing $I$. This means that in $R/I$ there is exactly one prime ideal, and then $\dim(R/I)=0$.